# Undoing the changes Spree_fancy has done to listing products

Tags: spree

I would like to undo the changes that spree_fancy theme has made to the listing products. In the original Spree, I received products with 'columns three' when I browsed a taxon.

```
<div data-hook="taxon_products">
<ul id="products" class="inline product-listing" data-hook="">
<li id="product_3" class="columns three alpha" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="" data-hook="products_list_item">
<div class="product-image">
<a class="info" title="Ruby on Rails Baseball Jersey" itemprop="name" href="/products/ruby-on-rails-baseball-jersey">Ruby on Rails Baseball Jersey</a>
<span class="price selling" itemprop="price">$19.99</span>
</li>
```

However, spree_fancy theme inserted another nested unordered list and set the class to "columns four". I would like to undo these changes. My first guess was to browse through the overrides, but I couldn't find the caused file.

```
div data-hook="taxon_products">
<ul id="products" class="inline product-listing" data-hook="">
<li class="product-row">
<ul>
<li id="product_18" class="columns four alpha" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="" data-hook="products_list_item">
<div class="product-image">
<a class="info" title="Sunflower Clip Arts" itemprop="name" href="/products/sunflower-clip-arts">Sunflower Clip Arts</a>
<span class="price selling" itemprop="price">$4.00</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The override happens here:

https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/596d11e09343a1ce716b4c34bcd3802765728c46/app/overrides/spree/shared/_products/group_products_list_by_3_in_row.html.erb.deface

If you place an empty file at `app/overrides/spree/shared/_products/group_products_list_by_3_in_row.html.erb.deface` and restart your web server, this override should not longer be applied.